# $G$ and $G'$ finite groups. Bijection $f$ sending $G$ to $G'$, s.t. for all $g\in G$ the order of $g$ is equal to the order of $f(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove or disprove: Let $G$ and $G'$ be finite groups. If there is a bijection $f$ sending $G$ to $G'$, so that for every $g\in G$ the order of $g$ is equal to the order of $f(g)$, then $G\cong G'$.

Think it is false because this bijection *f* has to be an homomorphism in the first place? Otherwise, would not work?

Comment: It's false because there are examples of finite groups having the same number of elements of each order. The smallest example is a pair of groups of order 16. Funny, this question just came up yesterday, I don't remember whether it was here or on MO.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_p= \left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_p \right\}$ be the Heisenberg group (with $p \geq 3$ a prime number). Then $H_p$ has $p^3$ elements with $p^3-1$ of order $p$, exactly as $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^3$. Of course, they are not isomorphic: one is abelian and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the quaternion group (the nonabelian group of order 8 that isn't the dihedral group), let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$, then $Q\times C_2$ and $C_4\times C_4$ both have 1 element of order 1, 3 of order 2, and 12 of order 4, but are not isomorphic (one is, the other isn't, abelian).